# Nativescript angular offline app tutorial

Tags: synchronization, nativescript, nativescript-angular, offlineapps, offline-mode

do you know where can I get full tutorial on building an android app using nativescript angular which is offline-first and could sync with remote server (rest api) using mysql database?

This is my first time to learn how to build an android app using nativescript angular and I need to learn how to build an offline-first app which could sync everything that change on local to remote server(mysql). I do have a rest api built with laravel. Could you guide me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can just highlight some of the key points to you, don't have any tutorial ...

You need to store data locally :

- If you need a complex database, relations, etc, I suggest sqlite.. So go with https://github.com/nathanaela/nativescript-sqlite
- optionnaly an orm can be usefull to work with sql .. I use typeorm successfuly with nativescript-sqlite : https://typeorm.io/#/

You need to architecture your app logically in layers :

- components display screens and fetch data directly from your local database (what I call a repository)
- repository get data from database and send it to the layer which need it (components)
- repository also fetch new data from network and fill up your local database
- your components needs to be aware that your local database got updated => use https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs
- network services (list of all the apis you'll call)
- network models (and conversion from/to databaseModel)
- database DAO
- database models
- etc

You need to detect online/offline :

- use https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/connectivity

If you have massive i/o, :

- maybe you should aim (from the start) to handle all your imports to be running in a service worker (good luck) https://github.com/NativeScript/worker-loader to not freeze your UI (js run in a single main thread)

Then you'll need to code your own synchronisation logic ;)

Good luck